# Добавление уведомления в календарь и пуш уведомления

Tags: java, android, android-notification, calendar

Пытаюсь сделать приложение по Типу "Task Manager" - чтобы можно было например написать заметку / задачу, и можно было поставить "уведомление о задаче", например в календаре (выбрать день и время) или что то типа уведомления в snack баре.
Календарь - стандартный, поставляемый вместе с ПО Android.
Каким образом это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Мало информации. В каком календаре? У вас свой календарь? Или вы хотите использовать например гугловский? Или иной? На самом деле этих туториалов по таск менеджерам в гугле много.

Comment: Покажите результат ваших поисков по данному вопросу

Comment: @dinario Результатов нет, натыкался только на AlarmService, Notifications и тд. Пост дополнил

Answer (score 1):

**Если использовать не свой календарь.**

Схема проста. Вы перекладываете доставку уведомлений на календарь. Т.е. используете например `Google Calendar Api`. Тут могут быть некоторые проблемы. У пользователя могут быть выключены все синхронизации с гугл календарем или стоять сторонние календари без синхронизации. В таком случае пользователь не увидит эти события.

**Если самому отправлять push-уведомления.**

Поднимаете фоновую задачу с отправкой уведомления в определенное время ([документация по фоновым задачам](https://developer.android.com/guide/background), [документация по уведомлениям](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html)).

Определитесь с методом. Далее углубитесь в эту тему. И уже потом задавайте вопрос конкретно над участком кода, который у вас не работает.

Comment: Решил через DatePicker попробовать решить вопрос

Comment: @СергейБеляков так `DatePicker` всего лишь позволяет выбрать дату. Он не закроет вопрос по фоновым задачам и уведомлениям

Comment: Я это понимаю, но может подскажете - как я могу например после получения даты из DatePicker добавить эту дату / событие в календаре устройства (встроенный имеется ввиду)?

Comment: @СергейБеляков встроенный это какой? У кого-то это Samsung calendar, у других это mi calendar. У третих третий. У большинства из них есть синхронизация с google calendar. Используете Google Calendar Api, в ответе описал проблемы, которые могут быть

Answer (score 0):

Нашел на просторах всемирной паутины хороший пример связки DatePickerDialog + Notification

Вот [ссылка](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-an-android-notification-to-a-specific-date-in-the-future), может кому понадобится